# Split text file by line and rename based on string content

Tags: awk, split

I have a WINDOWS text file that contains the following in its own directory: It is called "test.txt"

Example Source File - test.txt:

```
hxxp://url.xxx/XX/file 1.txt
hxxp://url.xxx/XX/file 2.avi
hxxp://url.xxx/XX/file 3.mpg
```

The content of the first file would be:

```
hxxp://url.xxx/file 1.txt
```

The name of this file would be:

```
file 1.txt
```

My goal is to create separate text files containing each URL and named after the "file" part of the URL. So the first one would be "file 1.txt.txt" then "file 2.avi.avi" and so on. Split does this perfectly EXCEPT for naming the actual files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily done in `awk`. You just need to set the field separator to `/` and then print each line into a file whose name is the last field. Since the number of fields in `awk` is saved in the `NF` variable, you can get the last fields with `$NF`. Then, if you want all of them to have the txt extension, all you need is:

```
awk -F'/' '{print > $NF".txt"}' file
```

If, as seems to be the case based on your comments, your input file has Windows line endings, you need to remove the `\r` first:

```
sed 's/\r//' file | awk -F'/' '{print > $NF".txt"}'
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for file 3.  But for the other files it made some nonsensical files: FEI1YX~E and FSVB57~1

Comment: @Aaron then your input is not like what you show in your question. Edit your question and include an actual example that fails please.

Comment: Thanks for helping terdon. I apologize if I wasn't clear. I have a text file that contains exactly those sample urls in its own directory. It is called "test.txt" I then ran your command replacing "file" with "test.txt".  Three new files were created.  "file 3.mpg" and those other ones I already mentioned. My goal is to create text files containing each URL and named after the field with a ".txt" ending.  So the first one would be "file 1.txt.txt" then "file 2.avi.txt" and so on.  Split does this perfectly EXCEPT for naming the actual files.

Comment: @Aaron oh. Then please edit your question and clarify. By the way, you know that there is absolutely no reason to have any extension for a trext file, right? I mean `foo`, `foo.txt` and `foo.bar` are treated no differently on *nix systems.

Comment: @Aaron also, see update. If you really want that, just add `.txt`.

Comment: I can append it after the fact-true. So I'll revise my question as you suggested

Comment: This still has the same problem except there is now a txt extension which is awesome; 
Files created:
FEI1YX~E.TXT
file 3.mpg.txt
FSVB57~1.TXT

I feel like your solution is VERY close.

Comment: OK - I see the issue.  I am SSH'ing into my linux box and viewing the files in windows. when I ls that folder the file name is "file 1.txt?.txt" Not sure where that question mark is coming from

Comment: @Aaron eeek! OK, this is the sort of detail you *really* need to mention. That's a windows text file then, so its lines don't end with a `\n` as they do in the *nix world, but with Windows-style line endings: `\r\n`. So the `\r` is taken as part of the file name and that is being displayed as `?` by `ls`. As I said, your example doesn't represent your actual data. See updated answer.

Comment: LOL. Noob indeed. I guess collation matters :) Edited.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I learned more than I expected to :)